# how to install ROS packages on multiple computers without using internet

Tags: ros, multiple, packages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can able to install ROS packages on single system, which is running on Ubuntu successfully.

But I need to install the packages to more than one systems without connecting to Internet, because my internet bandwidth is low.

Please help me out, to suggest, how to download the packages and save it on local storage/CD/DVD and start installing from it.

it is possible or i always depends on Internet for each system installation.

Note : some system are in different configurations, so taking GHOST files is not feasible

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38733/how-to-install-ros-packages-on-multiple-computers-without-using-internet/) by [chandrasekar1](https://answers.ros.org/users/2835/chandrasekar1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-07-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [akrv](https://answers.ros.org/users/8111/akrv/) on 2013-11-22**:
hi, did you find a way to do this?
I have computer that cannot be connected to the internet
It acts as the robot controller and I need to install ros on it?
how much possible it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If all your computers are running Ubuntu, the easiest way to go is probably to setup a local Debian repository containing the ROS packages. See `apt-mirror` for instance to learn how to do so.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2012-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2